# Double click in excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, double-click

I am using excel 2016 with all protection set off or as low as possible. I want to make a double click on a cell.

I have pasted the code in "module 1", directly into the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox ("WHAT?")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code in `Sheet1` or whatever one you want. These events are not fired in modules...

`Worksheet_SomeEvent(...)` are Worksheet functions so the code for such must be placed in worksheets in order to fire.

Comment: I already did that and it didnt work.... just tried it aggain after a complete restart of the PC and it works -.-

Comment: This *ought* to work (which is why I upvoted it). Presumably you're not naming a module 'Sheet1'? This code needs to be in the VBA for the specific worksheet.